# IGZ0201W and IGZ0035S errors in COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe

```
      *-----------------------
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
      *-----------------------
       PROGRAM-ID.    TOPACCTS
       AUTHOR.        Sohan Kundu.
      *--------------------
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
      *--------------------
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT PRINT-LINE ASSIGN TO PRTLINE.
           SELECT ACCT-REC   ASSIGN TO ACCTREC.
      *-------------
       DATA DIVISION.
      *-------------
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  PRINT-LINE RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS RECORDING MODE F.
       01  PRINT-REC.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FIRST-NAME-O   PIC X(11).
           05  FILLER         PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
           05  LAST-NAME-O    PIC X(22).
           05  FILLER         PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
           05  ACCT-BALANCE-O PIC X(12).
           05  FILLER         PIC X(30) VALUE SPACES.
      *
       FD  ACCT-REC RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS RECORDING MODE F.
       01  ACCT-FIELDS.
           05  FIRST-NAME         PIC X(11).
           05  LAST-NAME          PIC X(22).
           05  FILLER             PIC X(28).
           05  ACCT-BALANCE       PIC X(12).
           05  FILLER             PIC X(7).
      *
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  FLAGS.
           05 LASTREC          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
      *
       01  TOTAL-CLIENTS.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(14) VALUE
              '# OF RECORDS: '.
           05 CLIENTS             PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(63) VALUE SPACES.
      *
       01  HEADER-1.
           05  FILLER PIC X(30) VALUE 'REPORT FOR TOP ACCOUNT HOLDERS'.
           05  FILLER PIC X(50) VALUE SPACES.
      *
       01  HEADER-2.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(05) VALUE 'Year '.
           05  HDR-YR         PIC 9(04).
           05  FILLER         PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(06) VALUE 'Month '.
           05  HDR-MO         PIC X(02).
           05  FILLER         PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(04) VALUE 'Day '.
           05  HDR-DAY        PIC X(02).
           05  FILLER         PIC X(53) VALUE SPACES.
      *
       01  HEADER-3.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(11) VALUE 'First Name '.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(10) VALUE 'Last Name '.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(14) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(08) VALUE 'Balance '.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(35) VALUE SPACES.
      *
       01  HEADER-4.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(11) VALUE '-----------'.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(10) VALUE '----------'.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(14) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(08) VALUE '--------'.
           05  FILLER         PIC X(35) VALUE SPACES.
      *
       01 WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA.
           05  WS-CURRENT-DATE.
               10  WS-CURRENT-YEAR         PIC 9(04).
               10  WS-CURRENT-MONTH        PIC 9(02).
               10  WS-CURRENT-DAY          PIC 9(02).
           05  WS-CURRENT-TIME.
               10  WS-CURRENT-HOURS        PIC 9(02).
               10  WS-CURRENT-MINUTE       PIC 9(02).
               10  WS-CURRENT-SECOND       PIC 9(02).
               10  WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS PIC 9(02).
      *
      *------------------
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *------------------
       OPEN-FILES.
           OPEN INPUT  ACCT-REC.
           OPEN OUTPUT PRINT-LINE.
      *
       WRITE-HEADERS.
           MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA.
           MOVE WS-CURRENT-YEAR  TO HDR-YR.
           MOVE WS-CURRENT-MONTH TO HDR-MO.
           MOVE WS-CURRENT-DAY   TO HDR-DAY.
           WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HEADER-1.
           WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HEADER-2.
           MOVE SPACES TO PRINT-REC.
           WRITE PRINT-REC AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES.
           WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HEADER-3.
           WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HEADER-4.
           MOVE SPACES TO PRINT-REC.
      *
       READ-NEXT-RECORD.
           PERFORM READ-RECORD
            PERFORM UNTIL LASTREC = 'Y'
            PERFORM IS-BALANCE-HIGH
            PERFORM READ-RECORD
            END-PERFORM
           .
      *
       CLOSE-STOP.
           WRITE PRINT-REC FROM TOTAL-CLIENTS.
           CLOSE ACCT-REC.
           CLOSE PRINT-LINE.
           STOP RUN.
      *
       READ-RECORD.
           READ ACCT-REC
           AT END MOVE 'Y' TO LASTREC
           END-READ.
      *
       IS-BALANCE-HIGH.
           IF FUNCTION NUMVAL-C(ACCT-BALANCE) > 8500000 THEN
              ADD 1 TO CLIENTS
              PERFORM WRITE-RECORD
           END-IF.
      *
       WRITE-RECORD.
           MOVE FIRST-NAME   TO  FIRST-NAME-O.
           MOVE LAST-NAME    TO  LAST-NAME-O.
           MOVE ACCT-BALANCE TO  ACCT-BALANCE-O.
           WRITE PRINT-REC.
      *
```

I want to read the account details from an input file and print if the balance is more than 8500000.

The code is showing the following error:

```
 IGZ0201W A file attribute mismatch was detected. File PRINT-LINE in program TOPACCTS had a record length of 81 and
          the file specified in the ASSIGN clause had a record length of 80.
 IGZ0035S There was an unsuccessful OPEN or CLOSE of file PRTLINE in program TOPACCTS at relative location X'1E8'.
          Neither FILE STATUS nor an ERROR declarative were specified. The status code was 39.
          From compile unit TOPACCTS at entry point TOPACCTS at compile unit offset +000001E8 at entry offset +000001E8
          at address 1B8001E8.
```

Comment: Hi Sohan and welcome to SO! While you wait for answers (I'll edit your question for formatting, you may want to view the edit later) you could [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You should show the **JCL** that you are using to run the program. What the message is indicating is the file assigned to DD PRTLINE has a length of **81** bytes while in the program it is defined as **80** bytes.

Comment: Bookmark this page: [COBOL FILE STATUS CODES](http://ibmmainframes.com/references/a27.html)  Print files are generally defined as FBA with a carriage control character as the first character.

Comment: If you use AFTER ADVANCING you need to account for the leading 1 byte carriage control character.  Either remove AFTER ADVANCING or declare your RECORD CONTAINS as 81.

Comment: @SimonSobisch did you get it to work?

Comment: @SimonSobisch euh ... yes ... indeed ... mea culpa ...

Comment: @Sohan did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

In the JCL that you are using to execute this program (as a batchjob), within the step with `EXEC PGM=TOPACCTS`, make sure that you use a DD-card for your output file `PRTLINE` which looks similar to this:

```
//PRTLINE  DD DISP=(NEW,CATLG),DSN=YOUR.DSN.GOES.HERE,
//             UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(5,5)),
//             RECFM=FB,LRECL=80
```

That way you'll avoid the status code '39', which indicates that there is a mismatch between your record length of 80 (as shown in your program with `CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS`), and whatever you specified in your JCL's DD-card.